# ScalaJS enumeration

Tags: scala, scala.js

I was trying to use enums for [AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster)

```
class Toaster extends js.Object{
  // see https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-    Toaster/blob/master/toaster.js#L58
  def pop(`type` : ToasterType,title : String,body:String) : Unit = js.native
}
```

With an enum like this

```
object ToasterType extends Enumeration{
  type ToasterType = Value
  val Success = Value("success")
  ...
```

}

And then calling like

```
toaster.pop(ToasterType.Success, "some title", "text")
```

When the toaster is popped there is no title or text. When i use a string type on the `pop` definition and pass `"success" all works as expected.

(i used http://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html and https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/38. Thought the above should work, no?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala `Enumeration`s are not `String`s, so this should not work. You have to use `String`, which is the only thing that is a JavaScript `string`.

Comment: There's no magic in Scala.js. What you *can* do is implicit-pimp a variant of `pop` that takes your enumeration, and calls the original `pop` method, passing `tpe.toString()` for the `type` parameter. You do not need language support nor macros for this.